# Архитектура таблиц БД для хранения состояния этапов стогласования

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, workflow

Вопрос заключается в архитектуре БД, а точнее в том, каким образом лучше построить таблицы для процессов согласования.
Теперь более подробно.

Существуют основные таблицы:
**ks3** - содержит карточки, которые необходимо согласовывать;
**ks3_stage_workflow** - содержит стадии согласования, по которым идет вновь созданная карточка;
**group** - содержит группы с пользователями, которые участвуют в согласовании на каждом этапе согласования;
**ks3_stage_workflow_group** - промежуточная таблица отношения ManyToMany

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделано сейчас:
Пользователь создает карточку в таблице `ks3` и она идет по этапам согласования. Проблема данного подхода в том, что стадии согласования могут меняться и люди в группах тоже и это будет меняться в уже созданной или уже закрытой карточке, что неправильно.
Т.е. нужно при создании карточки запоминать этапы согласования и группы с людьми в них, и помещать в отдельную таблицу. Так же может быть ситуация, что для каждой конкретной карточки будет необходимо удалить целую группу с людьми из какого-нибудь этапа согласования или удалить только одного человека внутри группы. Следовательно нужно избавиться от связи между таблицами `ks3` и `ks3_stage_workflow` и создавать отдельную таблицу которая будет хранить в себе этапы с группами для каждой конкретной карточки.

Собственно вопрос, как лучше организовать эту таблицу с таким большим набором настраиваемых параметров? Помещать огромный json с этими настройками в ячейку не хочется.

Comment: А что фиксируется в ks3_stage_workflow_group, что вся группа целиком согласовала карточку ? я отдельных людей тут не вижу, т.е. согласование делает именно группа, а не отдельный человек ? Так, на вскидку, нужна таблица с ks3_id, например номером стадии и применяемым stage. при первой связи ks3 с первым stage сразу заполнять таблицу всеми этапами из stage_workflow на момент этой операции. и потом в ней в уже созданных записях только отмечать состояния "согласовано".

Comment: Но тогда возникает вопрос а что должно происходить если согласование прошло половину стадий и в этот момент что то изменилось в stage с порядком стадий. надо ли в ранее созданной, но не завершенной карточке срочно менять цепочку (что сильно усложняет логику) или нужна все таки та, что была на момент ее создания

Comment: @Mike В ks3_stage_workflow_group указан id группы с людьми которые должны поучаствовать в согласовании на определенном этапе, каждый член группы. Отвечая на второй комментарий, сами стадии после создания карточки неизменны, могут меняться группы внутри каждой стадии и набор людей внутри группы

Comment: А где вы тогда фиксируете что конкретный человек согласовал

Comment: @Mike пока нигде, это еще некий прототип и нужно решить, в том числе, этот вопрос созданием новой таблицы хранения состояния согласования

Comment: Тогда нам надо две таблицы. в одной ks3_id, state_workflow_id, state. Если стадии должны быть на момент создания карточки то сразу при создании пишем в нее все стадии, которые должны быть пройдены. Как только все люди из всех групп данной стадии поставили согласие, ставим на этой стадии признак что она пройдена, что бы к ней больше не возвращаться, даже если в ней добавятся группы/люди. И таблица ks3_id, user_id, state (может еще group_id если надо помнить в какой группе был чел когда согласовал). тут фиксируем согласования конкретных людей и на триггерах на нее можно выставлять state стадии